# How to use a tuple as dictionary key set

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I parse a JSON file to a dictionary, example JSON data below

```
 "environmental": {
      "temprature": {
           "test" : "temprature",
           "unit": "c", 

           "now": 12.65,
           "now_timestamp": "10-06-2019 08:02:18", 

           "min": "12.5", 
           "min_timestamp": "03-06-2019 07:40:02", 

           "max": "32.84", 
           "max_timestamp": "03-06-2019 04:30:03"
      },
```

I would like to know if there is a way one could get one of these values using either a string or tuple

Expected Outcome,

```
logging.info(dictionary_page_data_file['environmental']['temprature']['now'])
```

I have tried this

```
thistuple = ("environmental", "temprature", "now")
logging.info(dictionary_page_data_file[thistuple])
```

This has to be dynamic enough to accommodate various levels of dictionary's

Comment: No, dictionaries do not support this, as a `tuple` is a valid key, and it would be ambiguous, although you could write a function to translate a tuple or a string to a series of indexing operations

Comment: Related: [Dynamic dict value access with dot separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38832563/1639625) and a few similar ones.

Comment: You can create a new object and implement the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods to use custom keys. An example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486387/implement-list-like-index-access-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a small function that recursively walks through the dictionary, similar to the answer linked by @tobias_k in the comments:

```
dictionary_page_data_file = {
  "environmental": {
      "temprature": {
           "test" : "temprature",
           "unit": "c", 

           "now": 12.65,
           "now_timestamp": "10-06-2019 08:02:18", 

           "min": "12.5", 
           "min_timestamp": "03-06-2019 07:40:02", 

           "max": "32.84", 
           "max_timestamp": "03-06-2019 04:30:03"
      }}}

def get_keys(keys, d):
  if not keys:
    return d
  key = keys[0]
  return get_keys(keys[1:], d[key])

print(get_keys(('environmental', 'temprature', 'now'), dictionary_page_data_file))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, not to sure how exactly this works but seems simple and clean :-)

Comment: one question, why would one do return get_keys(keys[1:], d[key]) and not just get_keys(keys[1:], d[key])

Comment: @WernerVenter You mean without return? Then the function would never return any result. Since it also doesn't modify the data in-place, nothing would happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can make temporary dict with keys as tuple:

```
data = {
 "environmental": {
      "temprature": {
           "test" : "temprature",
           "unit": "c",

           "now": 12.65,
           "now_timestamp": "10-06-2019 08:02:18",

           "min": "12.5",
           "min_timestamp": "03-06-2019 07:40:02",

           "max": "32.84",
           "max_timestamp": "03-06-2019 04:30:03"
      }
}}

def keys_values(d, current_key=()):
    for k, v in d.items():
        yield current_key + (k, ), v
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            yield from keys_values(v, current_key + (k, ))

transformed_dict = {k: v for k, v in keys_values(data)}

print(transformed_dict[("environmental", "temprature", "now")])
print(transformed_dict[("environmental", "temprature", "min")])
print(transformed_dict[("environmental", "temprature", "max")])
```

Prints:

```
12.65
12.5
32.84
```